# Why is the implementation of Object.equals() not using hashCode()?

Tags: java, equals

or *"Why do the Sun/Oracle guys force us to override both equals() and hashCode() everytime?"*

[Everyone knows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) that, if you override equals() or hashCode() of an object, you have to override the other one, too, because there is a contract between those two:

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method [i.e. equals()] is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.
>   -- *[API doc of Object.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)*

Why isn't it implemented that way in the Object class:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return this.hashCode() == obj.hashCode()
}
```

If they did this, it would have saved the rest of the world from having to implement both methods. It would be enough to override only hashCode().

I guess the guys had some good reason not to do this. I just cannot see it - please clear this up for me.

Comment: Perhaps because of this: if two objects are equal, their hashcodes will be equal, but if two objects' hashcodes are equal, that is not enough information to guarantee that the objects themselves are equal because of this fact: hashes can collide.

Comment: Different objects can still have the same `hashcode()`. There are only `2^32` `int`s.

Comment: Common logic error: `x -> y` does not mean that `y -> x`.

Comment: Incidentally a much shorter version of your code would be `this.hashCode() == obj.hashCode()`. It would also avoid auto-boxing (and it would still be incorrect ;-))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `a.equals(b)` returns true then `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` must evaluate to `true`.

The opposite is *not true*! It's perfectly valid to have two objects where `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` is true, but `a.equals(b)` is false.

In fact, that's *necessary*. There are 2<sup>32</sup> possible return values for `hashCode()`. At any given moment a JVM can hold *more than* 2<sup>32</sup> objects (given there's enough memory, which is quite possible these days). Assuming that none of the objects are equal to each other (easy to do, just let them be `"s1"`, `"s2"`, ...), then you're *bound* to have a collision of checksums (see [Pidgeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)).

In fact, this is the simplest possible `hashCode` implementation that's *correct* (but otherwise *terribly bad*) for *every class*<sup>*</sup>:

```
public int hashCode() {
  return 0;
}
```

It magically fulfills all the requirements of [the general `hashCode()` contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

<sup>* except for those classes that have a defined and documented `hashCode` algorithm that they must implement, the prime example being [`String.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29).</sup>

Comment: Good point, but the documentation of hashCode() also tells us this: "However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hashtables." But this recommendation is not consistent with the standard implmentation. If your class can have more than 2^32 different instances, you can still override equals().

Comment: An example with strings is `"FB"` and `"Ea"`.

Comment: @FrancoisBourgeois: yes, and that's why the implementation I showed above is a *bad idea*. And producing a [perfect hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) isn't always easy, even in those cases where it's possible. So *assuming* that it's always implemented, is a pretty risky move.

Answer (score 3):

Joachim is correct, but there's another reason: Efficiency.

Calculating a hash code can be expensive, and this effort would be unnecessarily incurred if `equals()` was invoked, but `hashCode()` never was.

There are lots of cases where this would be the case; only classes like `Hashtable` (or those that use it) invoke `hashCode()`.

Comment: Aye! A `equals()` is usually quicker (especially if the objects are un-equal) than the corresponding `hashCode()` call.

Answer (score 1):

There is an infinite number of objects which have the same hashcOde.  This means you cannot compare the hashCde alone.

A simple example is `Long.hashCode()`: Every `Long` value that is a multiple of `1L << 32 + 1` has a hashCode of `0`.